# Python-3.6 How can I print all outcomes at the end instead of after each input?

Tags: string, python-3.x, loops, int, output

Sorry guys but I'm confused about how to solve this...

Program **takes a series of separate and random int inputs, compares each new int to the previous** (higher, lower, equal): e.g, first number = 10, next number = 5, output = lower. This loops until user enters [0]

But I now want to change it so that **all the outputs are at the end instead of 1 after each pair**. Let's say overall input is 2, 3, 6, 6, 5, 1 [0]: print statement should be only after [0] which would say, e.g., higher higher equal lower lower (all in one statement).

*Things I've tried... print(a) but of course (a) gets reassigned to each new number..... tried (rookie mistake): if b < a: b = "higher" but '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'...... tried a list but error: expected list but received int...... another error (can't remember what I tried): int object is not iterable. (Also, I know I should probably have some elifs instead of all these ifs but that's not causing problems...)*

My code:

```
z = 0
done = False
a = int(input("Enter first number: "))
while not done:
    b = int(input("Enter next number [0 = done]: "))
    if b != z: #while program not done
        if b > a:
            print("higher")
        if b == a:
            print("equal")
        if b < a:
            print("lower")
        a = b #second number becomes first and repeat
    else:
        done = True
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track the responses, print at the end.

```
z = 0
done = False
a = int(input("Enter first number: "))
track_comparisons = []
while not done:
    b = int(input("Enter next number [0 = done]: "))
    if b != z: #while program not done
        if b > a:
            track_comparisons.append('higher')
        elif b == a:                       #change to if, elif, else
            track_comparisons.append('equal')
        else:
            track_comparisons.append("lower")
        a = b #second number becomes first and repeat
    else:
        for response in track_comparisons:
            print(response, end=' ')
        done = True
```

Comment: This is nice, thank you. But it has a couple of issues: errors on "equal" (such as 5 and 5) and restarts the program along with the responses. Unfortunately my coding skill is not high enough to know why!

Comment: Check it again, I accidentally put append.append, where there should only be one append.

Comment: Yes, now it works nicely. Thank you! It's weird the difference one little .append can make!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following -

```
z = 0
ans = []
done = False
a = int(input("Enter first number: "))
while not done:
    b = int(input("Enter next number [0 = done]: "))
    if b != z: #while program not done
        if b > a:
            #print("higher")
            ans.append("higher")
        if b == a:
            #print("equal")
            ans.append("equal")
        if b < a:
            #print("lower")
            ans.append("lower")
        a = b #second number becomes first and repeat
    else:
        done = True

print(ans)
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer is -1 because it very nearly does what I'm looking for and does not overcomplicate the program which is a plus. Only difference is I want an output like: higher higher lower equal... rather than ['higher'], ['higher'], ['lower'], [equal],....